# How to split a string into substrings that are sandwiched or separated by the same letter in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
const str = "abbbaba";
```

I am looking for a way to split this string in groups of sandwiched letters, or all remaining letters.

### Examples

My string should be split into this:

```
["abbba", "ba"]
```

Where "abbba" is the first substring because it starts and ends with an "a".
The last substring starts with a "b", but there is
no ending "b", so it just takes the rest of the string.

Another scenario:

```
const str2 = "bbbabaa"
```

It should be split like this:

```
["bb", "bab", "aa"]
```

### Closest attempt

The following is my closest attempt for string `"abbabbabba"` which returns
`["abba", "bb", "a", "bb", "a"]`
instead of
`["abba", "bb", "abba"]`

```js
function splitSandwichedLetters(str) {
  const result = [];
  let start = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === str[start] && (i === str.length - 1 || str[i + 1] !== str[start])) {
      result.push(str.slice(start, i + 1));
      start = i + 1;
    }
  }

  if (start < str.length) {
    result.push(str.slice(start));
  }

  return result;
}

// Test 
const str1 = "abbabbabba";


console.log(splitSandwichedLetters(str1)); // Output: ["abbba", "ba"]
```

Comment: it is not clear to me why do you expect ["abba", "bb", "abba"] from "abbabbabba" and not : ["abba", "b","bab","ba"] ... tecnically  "bab" is the next sandwich or i'm wrong

Comment: Am going with the next similar closest neighbor;  for example; consider ``["abbabba"]``; starting with the first index `"a"` we check the next closest  `"a"` neighbor  so we will have `"abba"`, after that we move to the next substring we find `"b"`, we then check the next nearest `"b"` so we get `"bb"`; we then go to the next substring we find `"a"` which is remaining; so we will have; ``["abba","bb","a"]``

Comment: @AbednegoNasila ... but neither of the `b`'s nor the `bb` match itself fulfill any of the criteria of ... _"sandwiched or separated by the same letter"_. A regex which casts the OP's originally stated requirement into a pattern looks like this ... [`/(\p{L})(?!\1).+?\1/gu`](https://regex101.com/r/BnSiGm/1). But of cause it fails at an exception from the pattern like I consider a match of `bb` to be. (Thus I'm with _emilianoc_.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the iteration following a slice - `i` will be equal to `start`, and that breaks things because you'll be checking to see if a letter is equal to itself instead of equal to a letter occurring later. Fix it by incrementing `i` when you do a slice.

```js
function splitSandwichedLetters(str) {
  const result = [];
  let start = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === str[start]) {
      result.push(str.slice(start, i + 1));
      start = i + 1; // this means that next iteration i will be equal to start
      i++; // so increment i to avoid that
    }
  }

  if (start < str.length) {
    result.push(str.slice(start));
  }

  return result;
}

// Test 
const str1 = "abbabbabba";


console.log(splitSandwichedLetters(str1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the first char, keep a sub word, and a list of the result words:

```js
const splitter = (word) => {
  const ans = [];

  let first_char = '';
  let sub_word = '';

  for (const c of word) {
    sub_word += c;

    if (c === first_char) {
      ans.push(sub_word);
      sub_word = '';
      first_char = '';
    } else if (first_char === '') {
      first_char = c;
    }
  }

  if (sub_word !== '') {
    ans.push(sub_word); // last hanging bit
  }

  return ans;
}

console.log(splitter('abbbaba')); // [ 'abbba', 'ba' ]
console.log(splitter('bbbabaa')); // [ 'bb', 'bab', 'aa' ]
```